# mbed MemoryPool - is it usable for nontrivial classes?

Tags: c++, mbed

I'm looking into using mbed's [MemoryPool](https://os.mbed.com/docs/v5.7/reference/memorypool.html) API, however it seems to be oriented for simple POD types.

Inspecting the source of [MemoryPool.h](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/rtos/MemoryPool.h) seems to show that it's just taking memory blocks and presenting as is (or zeroing the block if using calloc) and not doing placement new.  I tried to follow the implementation, but got a bit lost in the syscall/weak-link maze.

My question:  Is this MemoryPool implementation usable with non-trivial C++ classes?  That is, if I make an allocation request, will the object constructor be called?  Or do I need to create an adapted MemoryPool to perform placement new operations (and the corresponding destructor calls) in order to obtain properly initialized and constructed objects?

I've opened an issue over at Github - https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/issues/5891

What has been reported so far reinforces what @Pharap has said in their answer.

Comment: I don't know MemoryPool particularly, but be aware that if it gives you only "raw" memory, you might need to care also about **alignment**. For instance, if it gives you 8 bytes of memory aligned to 4 byte address, you may not construct an object there (by using placement new) if it contains `double` member variable, which usually requires 8 byte alignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I make an allocation request, will the object constructor be called?

It would seem not.

Although I cannot find the source code for the `osMemoryPoolAlloc` function, there are a few other giveaways.

Firstly as you mentioned, calling `memset(item, 0, sizeof(T));` as the code does in `calloc` does indeed violate safe construction and destruction.

Secondly, the fact that the result of `osMemoryPoolAlloc` is being cast to `(T*)` implies that it returns a `void *` and knows nothing about the type it's allocating memory for other than perhaps its size.

> do I need to create an adapted MemoryPool to perform placement new operations (and the corresponding destructor calls) in order to obtain properly initialized and constructed objects?

Yes, you would.

But as @Daniel Langr mentions, there could potentially be alignment issues involved.

For what it's worth there's a comment at the bottom of the code that says:

`/* osMemoryPoolNew requires that pool block size is a multiple of 4 bytes. */`

and I believe most arm devices are 32-bit so I would assume it's probably safe to use placement new to create a type that has an alignment of 4 (which you can check with [`alignof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof).

However, my advice is to raise an issue about this over on the github page.
It seems that the code is not sufficiently documented, so without intimate knowledge of the code it would be hard to give a straight answer to your second question.

---

(Note that if the memory returned is suitable aligned then you could create a simple wrapper template class that adheres to the rules of an [allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator). This would permit use with allocator-enabled containers, though they would be limited in size as a result.)